# Delphi Prism DLL and IIS

Tags: asp.net, dll, isapi

My first Delphi Prism Web Application works fine locally on localhost:

localhost:58911/Default.aspx

What URL do I use to run this under IIS 7?

http://mywebsite.co.uk/AppName.dll/Default.aspx doesn't work. What am I missing here? Can I not use this syntax? Do I need to use URl re-writing ?

I (think I) have configured IIS 7.5 correctly. If I use URL 
http://mywebsite.co.uk/AppName.dll the browser tries to download the DLL.

(Apologies, old school Windows programmer struggling with the basics of the Web)

Comment: Which version of Prism?